# C char array printing as string error with accepting null termination?

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I have written a simple method that gets the input from a long string and prints it. I save my data in a char array and try to set the last element of said array to '\0' for null termination so that I may printf(%s,array).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 9
#define DEBUG 1
int QUIT = 0;
int assignNewBoard(void);

void main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  assignNewBoard();

  }

int assignNewBoard(void) {
  int row,col , count=0,maxCount=(MAX*MAX);
  char ch;
  char input[maxCount+MAX]; //our buffer with room for overflow.
                            //Hopefully never more than 90chars.

  while((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') {
    //input checks
    if(feof(stdin)){
      if(DEBUG) printf("Finished!\n");
      QUIT = 1;
    }

    count++;
    input[count] = ch;
  }

  if(DEBUG)printf("::");

  input[count+1] = '\0'; //null termination for printing.
  printf("%s\n",input);//This doesn't seem to happen at all in output!

  if(DEBUG) printf("We got %d count!\n", count);

  return 0;
}
```

But the above code does not print my char array as a string! Just prints empty after the :: in console!
So what am I doing wrong here? I had it working like this at one point in my code but now it isn't, not even in simplified file!

When run this should have a line "::(input)" but the line is simply "::" instead.

I am using GCC to compile.

Comment: added better explanation of problem.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, depending on what you actually want it to do. edit: it prints a string for me, what IDE/compiler are you using?

Comment: `count++;
    input[count] = ch;` --> `input[count++]=ch;...input[count] = '\0'; `

Comment: BLUEPIXY, I tried that, but on my GCC compiler I'm still getting same problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You increment `count` before doing anything with it, so the first character you read goes into `input[1]`. Array indices start at `0` in C; the value of the first character in the array, `input[0]`, is garbage and so the output you get may vary from time to time. (The behaviour is undefined).

You should also specifically check that `count` never gets so big that you run off the end of the buffer. If that does happen then it may cause your program to crash elsewhere and these errors can be difficult to debug.

Comment: Good catch, didn't even bother to check count before compiling and running. Works for me in Code Blocks, but all that means is that it probably tried to fix it during the build process. Never rely on the compiler to fix your mistakes :)

Comment: Great explanation! I moved my count++; after my assignment so I always start at [0] and that fixed everything! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Why you want to do all that..You can simply do it this way. Scanf string till \n and print it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        char str[90];
        scanf("%[^\n]",str);
        printf("%s",str);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: perhaps a homework assignment. As a CS Tutor I've seen plenty of assignments in classes where the instructor says "Use fgetc to accomplish this" or "Don't use sscanf" etc. If I ever become an instructor teaching any sort of programming I'm going to try to steer away from this sort of teaching. Teach best practices, then let the students work it out on their own, and maybe during feedback make suggestions for efficient best practices.

Comment: This is more efficient and I had it in mind for later but I wasn't sure how to format so I went with what I knew. Please tell me though: what will this return at EOF, or how can I notice I'm at EOF?